# rdlc report not downloading after publish

Tags: asp.net

my rdlc report not downloading after I publish the site  but it works on localhost. Any help would be appreciated. sorry for my grammar

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If Session("Branch") = 1 Then 
                Response.Redirect("~/samplePage1.aspx", False)
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
            ElseIf Session("Branch") = 2 Then
                Response.Redirect("~/samplePage2.aspx", False)
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Session("Error Message") = ex.Message
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: RDLC are xml files you need to copy and paste same rdlc file in published folder

Comment: but my rdlc are already there in my project.

Comment: Don't see any download code. Could be an issue in the sample pages.

Comment: I already resolved the issue. I tried changing rdlc's Build Action from "Embedded Resource" to "Content". Fortunately, It worked.